# The position of the expression "out of"

Tags: prepositions

As far as I know, the expression "out of" is usually located at the beginning of a sentence.  Can the expression "out of" be located in the middle of the sentence? as follows:

> Please send back to me only data, out of data I sent you yesterday,
>   related to a tomorrow meeting. I have deleted it by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence needs some fixes. You have several errors with articles and it makes more sense to rearrange things. Instead, let's look at this fixed version:

> Please send me only the data related to tomorrow's meeting out of the data I sent you yesterday.

I personally (as a native speaker) would use "[from](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/from)" instead. One of the uses of "from" is to indicate the source of something (definition 3).

But "out of" isn't wrong either. If you [look it up](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out), you'll see:

> **out of**: Indicating the source or derivation of something; from

---

This is, however, only one instance where "out of" is used in the middle of the sentence. There are many, many more:

> Get out of my house!

> Four out of five doctors recommend our product.

> I was sick recently, so I'm feeling out of it.

> We're out of milk.

Comment: You've answered the "text" of the question but I think avoided the "spirit".  In the context of "Out of the following choices, which is correct?" -- meaning to pick from a selection -- is it possible to use "out of" in the middle of the sentence?  I'm having trouble coming up with an example that doesn't require linguistic backflips.  Your example at the top doesn't feel *natural* -- perhaps it would be spoken but not written.